# .cshtml Razor Code Template (.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-core

I just started working with, NET and I'm not very familiar with razor code.
I want to remove redundancy in my razor (.Net) code, without a big mess. I have about a dozen, PDF generating .cshtml files with razor code in it and the number is growing. Each file is nearly the same. The whole structure is always the same, only the content is always different. Because the files are pretty big, I will make an abstract example (ignore the real meaning of the elements, the list could be a different div for example):

File 1:

```
<div>
  <p>
    @content
  </p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
     @comment
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

File 2:

```
<div>
  <p>
    @picture
  </p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <div>
        @link
        @metadata
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I thought it's not very clean to use @helper or @function for the different sections that are the same. The code would be not very clear to read with 10+ functions in it, that is only for the structure there.
I cant either just make a function to insert the value because sometimes there is, for example, a link or an additional div element inside the main structure.

At the end I want to have one place where I can change the basic structure, to change all structures, without going through 10+ files and change them one by one.

Is it possible to make such a "template"?

Comment: Have you try with the `DisplayTemplates` and `EditorTemplates` in folder Shared ? using `UIHint` decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Layout pages that define the overall structure. "Content", "Comment", etc are defined as sections in the layout, these sections get their content from the cshtml file that uses the layout. [Creating a Consistent Layout in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look).

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div>
  <p>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("content")) {
        @RenderSection("content", false)
    }
  </p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      @if (IsSectionDefined("comment")) {
          @RenderSection("comment", false)
      }
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

.cshtml that uses this layout

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
@section content {
    <div>My content</div>
}
@section comment {
    bla bla bla ...
}
```